# Show and Edit M2M filelds in both Admin Panel Models (django-select2)

Tags: django, python-3.x, jquery-select2

I have some problem with ModelSelect2MultipleWidget when I set him for custom field.

models.py

```
class Product(GenerateUniuqSlugMixin, BaseAbstractModel):
    name = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='Имя',
        max_length=255
    )
    slug = models.SlugField(
        verbose_name='Url',
        max_length=100
    )
    description = models.TextField(
        verbose_name='Описание',
        blank=True
    )
    price = models.ManyToManyField(
        'Price',
        verbose_name='Цена',
        blank=True,
        related_name='products'
    )

class Price(BaseAbstractModel):
    code = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='Уникальный Код',
        max_length=100,
        unique=True,
        db_index=True
    )
    price = models.DecimalField(
        verbose_name='Цена',
        max_digits=16,
        decimal_places=2
    )
    creation_date = models.DateField(
        verbose_name='Дата добавления',
        auto_now_add=True
    )
    update_date = models.DateField(
        verbose_name='Дата обновления',
        auto_now=True
    )
```

I want have opportunity for searching and connecting products from Price Admin Panel. And I added for forms next code:

```
class PriceAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    products = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Product.objects.all(),
        widget=ModelSelect2MultipleWidget(
            model=Product,
            queryset=Product.objects.all(),
            search_fields=['name__icontains'],
            attrs={'data-placeholder': 'Поиск в товарах', 'data-width': '50em'}
        ),
        required=False
    )
    class Meta:
        model = Price
        fields = (
            'code',
            'name',
            'price',
            'products',
        )
```

But it's not working and I don't know why, where my mistake? If I remove ModelSelect2MultipleWidget from widget attr I see default choice field, but he don't remeber my save choice he just show all queryset. It will be great if I can see input field which offer ModelSelect2MultipleWidget. 
Thank's.

My environment:
Django==2.0.2
django-select2==6.0.1